# Feed Style Similar to this

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've been pondering over this for around 3-4 hours and can't wrap my head around how to do it. I've been looking at [This Feed](http://dunked.com/examples) and trying to replicate it for a wordpress blog I'm working on, I've looked around numerous Jquery plugins but none seem to keep them in rows - Any help with this would be much appreciated.

The problem I am having is that the feed on the link above has a lovely and nice laid out feed, but it's not cascading like Pinterest, a keen eye might spot that each row is perfectly aligned and all start at the same position and end at the same position but the images are variable heights.

TL;DR

- Wanting a feed similar to the link supplied.
- Static Row Height
- Variable Image Height inside Row.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a table.

```
<table>
    <tr> //a table row
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then for the CSS:

```
table {
    position:relative;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    margin:1em auto 1em auto;
}
td {
    border-color:transparent;
    width:20%;
    height:450px;
    padding:0;
    margin:5
}
```

You can play around with the CSS, but a table is best for this kind of thing.